# Django exception shows url value in array

Tags: python, django

I get an exception `No connection adapters were found for "['https://uk-hairloom.atlassian.net/']/rest/agile/1.0/board?maxResults=50"` when hitting my `test_connection` method.

When I trace this back to the view and print the POST request object in a standard django view, the values are wrapped in an array and I don't understand why. Weird thing is if I do a GET for all objects using postman, they are not wrapped in array and appear as strings. FYI model fields are `TextField` NOT list.

```
class JiraDataViewSet(BaseModelViewSet):
    queryset = JiraData.objects.all().order_by("-id")
    serializer_class = JiraDataSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        IsAdmin,
    ]
    lookup_field = "uuid"

@action(detail=False, methods=["post"])
def test_connection(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    result = False
    if request.data:
        try:
            details = JiraData(**request.data)
            if details:
                if test_get_all_boards(details):
                    result = True
        except Exception as e:
            print('printing exception')
            print(e)
            pass
```

Exception looks like:

```
No connection adapters were found for "['https://uk- 
hairloom.atlassian.net/']/rest/agile/1.0/board?maxResults=50"
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.POST` and `request.GET` are instances of `django.http.QueryDict`. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects):

> In an **[HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest)** object, the **[GET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET)** and **[POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)**
> attributes are instances of **django.http.QueryDict**, a
> dictionary-like class customized to deal with multiple values for the
> same key. This is necessary because some HTML form elements, notably
> , pass multiple values for the same key.

Considering this it is not weird that they are represented as a list. Accessing the querydicts values using `__getitem__` (`request.POST['some_key']`) or `.get('some_key')` according to the documentation works like:

> Returns the value for the given key. If the key has more than one
> value, it returns the last value.

If we wanted the list of the values for a given key we could use it's `getlist` method:

```
values = request.POST.getlist('some_key') # returns a list of values or an empty list if matching key doesn't exist
```

Comment: Is there a way to see the actual values as they would be represented by the database?
Weirdly, further down the line when the code does its request to jira the exception thrown looks like `No connection adapters were found for "['https://uk-hairloom.atlassian.net/']/rest/agile/1.0/board?maxResults=50"` . This to me looks like the same issue, the array is wrapping the value.

Comment: @godhar and how do you access the values? You haven't shown the code for that in your question (plus if this really was the issue shouldn't you have mentioned that from the start in your question?...)

Comment: You are right, I just traced it back and assumed it happened at the view, since the view gave the value in an array as well. I updated the question.

Comment: after further investigation I understand your answer better. Indeed the POST request data was a `QueryDict`. The reason was because I was sending it as `w-xxx-urlencoded` content type. As soon as I switched it to raw JSON, the values were plain strings.